# Implement a queue which keeps non-decreasing

Tags: algorithm, queue

As everyone knows, a standard queue supports two basic operations: `insert` and `popout`. And `insert` occurs at the tail of the queue, while `popout` occurs at the head of the queue. Here, I have no idea whether I can keep this queue ordered, like non-decreasing, based on this two operations, or perhaps with some additional help functions to achieve that goal?

Comment: I guess, the concept you are looking for is "priority queue".

Comment: But don't you think priority queue only maintain ONE element maximum or minimum, not the entire queue keeps a specific order?

Comment: First, most (probably all) implementations keep order by insert a new element at the correct place, so `insert` is O(ln(n)) and `popout` is O(1) . Second, if the only operation to "observe" the queue is `popout`, it wouldn't even matter.

Comment: I agree with you. However, it's a task arranged by my Data structure teacher and I argued with him on this. I reckon he wants me to achieve this by using the BASIC `insert` and `popout` alongside a linear structure. But I just think it's impossible(or rather hard) to achieve that.(Maybe you can see the next answer for detailed info.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change `insert` function a little. Every time you `insert` into the queue you have to find the new element place in the queue it could be achieved with following algorithm:

Use a recursive function and every time check if your new element is greater than the element in the middle of the list, if not, try to insert new element in left side of queue else try to insert in the right side of queue, do it recursively until you find the proper place for the element.

Thin algorithm for insert is `O(lg(n))`.

For `popout` you could just do what you are done now, popout the last element.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Here maybe I'm a bit stubborn, is there any method to use something like a cache to maintain the queue, so that I can make the `insert` only at the tail of my queue?

Comment: @Allen_3 if you insert at the tail of the queue, your queue wouldnt be sorted! First you have to choose what you want.

Although you could first insert the new element then call a function to do the above algorithm, I think this is more suitable for you.

Comment: Yep. So, perhaps, it's impossible to do that if I can only do `insert` at the tail, with no further sort or something that basically not belongs to the queue's operation(in and out).

Comment: @Allen_3 seriously how could that be possible to have a sorted queue without sorting?